# rpm rename (obsolete) while updating deletes required folders

Tags: centos, rename, rpm, post-install

I have currently installed a version of rpm (x.rpm) that needs to be renamed in the next version (y.rpm). To accomplish this, I decided to obsolete the old (x.rpm) rpm. When I run the rpm –Uvh y.rpm on the new rpm here are the steps that takes place:

-Pre-transaction

-Pre-install

-Post install

-Pre uninstall

-Post uninstall

However, my post-uninstall script has some clean up steps that goes and does an rm –rf for some folders. The post-uninstall for both version of the rpm is exactly the same so now, when I installed the new rpm (y.rpm), some folders that were required by the new version gets removed because of the post-uninstall script.

How do I get around this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Does your problem somehow involve Gradle, or did you add that tag by mistake?

Comment: I am using gradle to create the rpm.

Comment: Did you end up coming up with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do:

1. create a newer version of x.rpm with changed post uninstall script that doesn't remove folders
2. update x.rpm on all machines
3. wait for a while (depending if this is an in-house project or an open project on the internet)
4. start deploying y.rpm